# Does closure serve as data privacy in currying and partial application in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to functional programming and was learning currying and partial application and the role of closure in implementation of currying and partial application in functional application. The question is Is it true that we use closure in currying and partial application as DATA PRIVACY only?

Comment: closures can be used to hide data from outside, but that's not the main purpose

Comment: @georg, the main purpose is that closures help to remember data that can be reused? Is this the main purpose? I really hope for your kind reply

Comment: @georg, Please sir I really need your kind help:(

Comment: Hi, have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)#Applications

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by data privacy.

If data privacy means "making sure your user privacy is secure" then no. Closures allow to create curried functions but people can still do stupid things:

```
const greetings = intro => name => {
  tweet(`Hello everybody! ${name} just executed this program`); //<~ waaat?!
  alert(`${intro} ${name}!);
};
```

If data privacy means "how can I keep some data safe from other programs" then yes it could do. e.g.

With this version, people can still tamper with `value`:

```
function volume_controls(value) {
  this.value = value;
}
volume_controls.prototype.up = function () {
  this.value = this.value + 1;
};
volume_controls.prototype.down = function () {
  this.value = this.value - 1;
};

var ctrl = new volume_controls(10);
ctrl.up(); //=> 11
ctrl.value = "boom";
ctrl.up(); //=> "boom1"
```

With a closure this would be impossible:

```
const volume_controls = value => ({
  up: () => ++value,
  down: () => --value
});

const ctrl = volume_controls(10);
ctrl.up(); //=> 11
ctrl.value = "boom"
ctrl.up(); //=> 12
```

Although from a functional programming perspective, tampering with your parameters isn't nice.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, just very briefly Why benefit does closure bring to the table when we use it with currying and partial application. Is it the ability to remember data? Is the ability to remember data what plays key role and closure helps to achieve that?

Comment: please I really need your help:(

Comment: @Dickens Yes a closure remembers the scope in which it has been created; hence you can use closures to curry functions.